# Definite derivative ratios

Tags: calculus, integration

Suppose we have

$\dfrac{\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b}  f(x) \: dx }{\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b} \: g(y)\: dy }  \: = t  $

what can we say on

$\dfrac{\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b}  f(x) \: \cdot \: \gamma(x)  \: dx }{\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b} \: g(y)\: \cdot \: \gamma(y)  \: dy }    $

with $\gamma$ being an integrable function having once $x$ as its domain and the other time $y$ as domain.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that it's not too much. It will all depend on $f$, $g$, and $\gamma$. Let's choose a simple example. Let $g(y)=1$. Then $$t=\int_a^bf(x)dx$$Let's simplify even more, assume $a=-1$, $b=1$ and $t=2$. One possible choice for $f$ would be $f_1(x)=1$, a second choice would be $f_2(x)=1+x$, and the third choice would be $f_3(x)=1-x$. Now let's choose $\gamma$ to be a function peaked at either $-1/2$, $0$, or $1/2$, such that the integral $$\int_{-1}^1\gamma(y) dy=1$$To simplify integral calculations (this is just an example), let's use a hat function of height $1$ and width $1$:$$\gamma_1(y)=\cases{1,x<0\\0,x\ge0}\\\gamma_2(y)=\cases{1,|x|<1/2\\0,|x|\ge1/2}\\\gamma_3(y)=\cases{0,x<0\\1,x\ge0}$$
Then for $f_1$, the second expression is always $1$, no matter which of the above $\gamma$ functions you choose. If you choose $f_2$, the expression for $\gamma_1$ will be $1/2$, for $\gamma_2$ will be $1$ and for $\gamma_3$ will be $3/2$. For $f_3$ the order changes.